# Correctly configure a test svn/apache server

Tags: svn, webdav, apache

I'm testing subversion, the base svnserve works, but I'm interested in testing the Apache/Httpd server.

I appear to be running into something, because regardless of what I type on the cmdline "svn list http://192.168.1.45/foo" I get something like

```
svn co http://192.168.1.45/Cool
svn: OPTIONS of 'http://192.168.1.45/Cool': 200 OK (http://192.168.1.45)
```

here's ny filestructure

```
ls /apps/CollegeDir/CollegeRepository
conf  db  format  hooks  locks  README.txt

ls /apps/CollegeDir/
atmp  baseCollegeSvn  CollegeRepository  CollegeRepositoryRoot

ls /apps/CollegeDir/CollegeRepositoryRoot/
cat    dog   car
```

I created the repository by using:

```
svnadmin create /apps/CollegeDir/CollegeRepository
```

I can access the repos for the svnserve by:

```
svn list svn://192.168.1.45/apps/CollegeDir/CollegeRepository/trunk/apps/CollegeRoot
```

as well as by the file by:

```
svn list file:///apps/CollegeDir/CollegeRepository/apps
CollegeDir/
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to get the svn list, using the http process. My issue is either in using the wrong http url path, or I've setup the svn portion of the apache http.conf/subversion.conf file incorrectly.

Here's what I have as a test in the subversion.conf file

```
<Location /trunk/apps/CollegeRoot>
   DAV svn
   SVNPath /apps/CollegeDir/CollegeRepository/
</Location>
```

The goal of the test, is to simply get a basic read/write for anyone with no auth process..

By the way, all of the folders/files are fully open (766) and "apache.apache" for the chown. This is to ensure the testing should work.

I've looked at various sites/threads but can't seem to pin down the issue.

Thoughts/comments are appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think:

```
<Location CollegeDir>
   DAV svn
   SVNParentPath /apps/CollegeDir/
   SVNListParentPath On
</Location>
```

should be accessible by

```
svn ls http://192.168.1.45/CollegeDir/CollegeRepository
```

You can get a list of all repositories available by pointing your browser to (note that this list is not supported by svnclients!)

```
http://192.168.1.45/CollegeDir/
```

---

Alternative:

```
<Location CollegeRepository>
   DAV svn
   SVNPath /apps/CollegeDir/CollegeRepository
</Location>
```

will be accessible under
should be accessible by

```
svn ls http://192.168.1.45/CollegeRepository
```

Comment: hey... tried your suggestions.. still not getting data back.. all i get back is 192.168.1.45 - - [11/Mar/2011:17:21:12 -0800] "OPTIONS /College HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "SVN/1.6.13 (r1002816) neon/0.29.3"
192.168.1.45 - - [11/Mar/2011:17:21:16 -0800] "OPTIONS /cc HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "SVN/1.6.13 (r1002816) neon/0.29.3"
[root@dell-1 /]#

Comment: aha.... turns out it was a permission issue regarding the repository/working copy files.   as a base test, simply set everything to 766, and to apache.apache for the chown.